# Arrow function does not notify redux state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, arrow-functions

I have a react component in react native that I want to handle hardwareBackButton manually.
I have different behavior when a redux state is true or false in backHandler function that I pass to hardwareBackPressListener.

```
const brandSelected = useSelector(state => state.map.brandSelected);
```

I have this useSelector in my component to access the state.
and I have useEffect function that I monitor the changes of this state: (that has correctly work and log the state when it changes to true or false.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(brandSelected); // this is false correctly   
}, [brandSelected]);
```

and finally I have a backHandler function that I pass it to hardwareBackPress Listener.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backHandler);
  return () => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backHandler);
  };
}, []);
```

and backHandler function:

```
const backHandler = () => {
  console.log('check, backhandler', brandSelected) // it logs true continuously
  if (brandSelected === true) {
    dispatch(
      dispatchItemToRedux({
        type: CATEGORIES_SELECTION,
        payload: {
          brandSelected: false,
        },
      }),
    );
    return true;
  }
  popScreen(Screens.Map);
  return true;
};
```

But this function does not notify that the brandSelected state changed. the first time it works  correctly and dispatch function and changes the redux state correctly and useEffect function log false correctly. but in other tries it does not work correctly and nothing changed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is a stale enclosure of the `brandSelected` in the `backHandler` function you passed to the `"hardwareBackPress"` event listener on the initial render cycle. `backHandler` function only ever has the value from the initial render cycle and will never update/re-enclose an updated value.

To resolve you should cache the `backHandler` state value in a React ref that you can reference in the callback handler.

```
const brandSelected = useSelector(state => state.map.brandSelected);
const brandSelectedRef = React.useRef(brandSelected);

useEffect(() => {
  brandSelectedRef.current = brandSelected;
}, [brandSelected]);
```

...

```
const backHandler = () => {
  console.log('check, backhandler', brandSelectedRef.current)
  if (brandSelectedRef.current) {
    dispatch(
      dispatchItemToRedux({
        type: CATEGORIES_SELECTION,
        payload: {
          brandSelected: false,
        },
      }),
    );
    return true;
  }
  popScreen(Screens.Map);
  return true;
};
```

An alternative would be to move `backHandler` *into* the `useEffect` hook setting the event listeners and use the `brandSelected` state as a dependency so the updated state value is re-enclosed in the callback.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const backHandler = () => {
    console.log('check, backhandler', brandSelected)
    if (brandSelected) {
      dispatch(
        dispatchItemToRedux({
          type: CATEGORIES_SELECTION,
          payload: {
            brandSelected: false,
          },
        }),
      );
      return true;
    }
    popScreen(Screens.Map);
    return true;
  };

  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backHandler);
  return () => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backHandler);
  };
}, [brandSelected]);
```

Comment: Yes It works correctly. thank you! but which solution is better for performance? If I add a listener repeatedly to my component and remove it and add again, it is good for my performance or first solution?

Comment: Because I have more than one state like this in my component

Comment: @Mohamadamin I prefer the first solution that mounts and adds the event listeners, once, and removes them upon unmounting, once, but this is subjective. In terms of performance there may be a *very slight* bit of overhead to remove and add a new listener, but I can't imagine it'd be very noticeable unless the `brandSelected` state is updating on the order of a per/render-cycle basis. Either should be fine.